# Appending variables to strings in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to create a simple function that takes a int and converts it to a time but as a string so that I can display it on the iPhone.

I can not get the string to concatenate right, here is the function any advice or help would be much appreciated.

```
- (string)countdown(int t) {
    for(int time = t; time >= 0; time--) {

        int h = time / 3600;
        int m = (time / 60) - (h * 60);
        int s = time % 60;

        NSString* timeString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: h, @":", m, @":", s];

        self.visualTimer.text = timeString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste actual code if you can. Why do you have a loop if you return at the end of the first iteration?

Comment: Please take a look at NSDateFormatter as well

Comment: ... I don't think you understand what `return` does.

Comment: how can loop return on every iteration???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
NSString* timeString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: h, @":", m, @":", s];
```

must be

```
NSString* timeString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d" h,m, s];
```

Be aware that you end the loop the first time you return `tempString`. Also, for a countdown, the construct you are using will run down rather quickly, if you wouldn't have the return within the loop. Consider reading up and using an `NSTimer`approach.

Edit: Your edited code will not produce visible results since the for loop will block the runloop and thus the UI will not get updated.

Comment: thank you for the headsup and the string fix. How can I do this without blocking the runloop? and still have the time update on the screen

Comment: Look into using `NSTimer` which allows to repeat a method in a defined time interval like every second or every 5 seconds. Or google for Countdown on iOS.. should give a couple of results you can start with.